# Socket connection works from pc but not Android tablet. Xamarin forms app

Tags: android, sockets, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a MikroTik router setup with bridge.
There are 2 ip addresses in the router, one for lan and one for wlan.
The ethernet ip is `192.168.0.22` the wlan ip is `192.168.0.21`.
This router is plugged into a robot PLC which has a Linux machine internally (no firewall), this machine gets the ether ip assigned.
On my PC I tested with SocketTest by connecting to the router and connecting to the ether IP. This all works as expected. But as soon as I want to connect from my Android tablet this connection won't work. I connect to the WiFi router on the Android tablet just as you would with any WiFi.

There is two things I tried, first I set the IP to static on the android device. The IP I use is the one set in the router. Then connecting simply says connection timed out after a couple of minutes. Second thing I tested is not using a static IP. The reason for this is that I also did not use a static IP on my PC. When doing this I almost immediately get Connection refused. However, on the server side I have no logging of a socket connection being refused.

My C# code:

```
IPAddress address = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.0.22");
IPEndPoint ipe = new IPEndPoint(address, 30003);
Socket socket = new Socket(SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp); 
socket.Connect(ipe);
```

I alos added the permissions in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <application android:label="Universal_ONE.Android" android:theme="@style/MainTheme"></application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

I also downloaded 2 different socket test apps on my Android device. They both say that a connection cannot be made.

Comment: `The ethernet ip is 192.168.0.22` I have no idea what that means. For my router the gateway ip is 192.168.0.1 and devices connecting to the router get ip's like 192.168.0.#. Is there something more?

Comment: It is a bridged network. The router itself has 1 ethernet port and a Wlan connection. The ethernet is configurable which I set to that IP, same goes for the Wlan. @blackapps